# Htaccess change hyphens to underscores

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed the structure of my links and am trying to 301 my old links to the new links to stop them all getting 404s

Old links

```
www.domain.comn/artistfirstname-artistsecondname/songfirstword-songsecondword
```

New links

```
www.domain.com/mp3/artistfirstname_artistsecondname-songfirstword_songsecondworld.html
```

I am trying to rewrite the old links to point to the new links but i need to change the dashes in the first link to underscores so i can do something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ mp3/$1-$2.html
```

Also needs to account for artists and songs that only have 1 word which means they wouldnt have dashes in the url to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mp3/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ /$1_$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mp3/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /mp3/$1-$2.html [L,R=301]
```

The first rule will iteratively replace dashes with underscores, but not redirect. The second rule makes sure that all dashes are gone, *then* redirect with the `/` being replaced with a dash.